# ¿Cómo puedo saber si una url es una imágen o un PDF?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

El problema mas grande es que ninguna url de las que recibo tienen extensión y al obtener el array con `get_headers` en php, me retorna `"Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"`,

¿Hay algún otro método de identificarles?

```
<?php
//var_dump(get_headers($row['url']));
if (in_array("Content-Type: application/pdf", get_headers($row['url']))) {
  ?>
  <div id="pdf{{$cd['id']}}-{{$row['idrow']}}" style="height: 70vh;"></div>
  <script>PDFObject.embed("{{$row['url']}}", "#pdf{{$cd['id']}}-{{$row['idrow']}}");</script>
  <?php
}else{
  ?>
  <img src="{{$row['url']}}" class="card-img-top" alt="row{{$row['idrow']}}">
  <?php
}
```

?>

Comment: Lastimosamente, eso de obtener que tipo de extensión tiene un archivo es un poco mas complicado, puesto que a no ser de que el archivo tenga una extension especifica (que la tenga en el mismo nombre del archivo al final), todos aquellos que no contengan la extensión en su nombre serán tratados como application/octet-stream que es un formato binario el cuál no se ejecuta directamente por seguridad, si te llega como text/html es porque no definiste esa cabecera en el frontend con un tipo diferente, lo cual seguro no es lo que deseas, puesto que desearias que fuese dinamico.

Comment: Por defecto la cabecera content-type tiene como tipo text/html, y en muchos casos si el content-type no es definido por nosotros y el archivo no tiene una extensión especifica definida en el nombre, el header content-type va a fallar obteniendo el tipo de documento que es haciendo que si no puede detectarlo como un tipo especifico, nos lo traiga como text/plain, application/octet-stream y en algunos casos text/html, esos son los mas frecuentes.

Comment: Curiosamente me enfrente a este problema pero quise solventarlo usando nodejs ya que estaba usando socket.io, así que lo que hice fue hacer que cuando hubiera un tipo desconocido se enviaran los primeros 80 bytes de informacion al servidor para ser analizados mediante herramientas mas especializadas de la shell de linux, por ejemplo exiftool (no viene con linux), y el comando file (viene con linux), aprovechando que desde node podemos obtener resultados de la shell, esta informacion luego es devuelta para poder verificar la extension del archivo y usarla.

Comment: Las buenas noticias es que en php existe una instruccion de la cual no recuerdo el nombre que te permite ejecutar también comandos de la shell, por lo que puedes intentarlo tambien desde php, esto en casos donde no haya una extension en el nombre (cuando no hay extension por alguna razon los navegadores fallan en saber que tipo de archivo son), por lo cual es buena idea intentarlo para cuando no hay una extension o cuando se falla al intentar obtener la extension.

Comment: @Riven en PHP si se usa apache se puede activar el mime type y leer las cabeceras del archivo nativo para saber qué tipo de archivo es

Comment: Es bueno saberlo, me gustaria ver un ejemplo puesto que eso no lo sabia, tu respuesta puede ser de mucha utilidad.